# IF function with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

```
=IF(A1=5, "green apple","red apple")
```

Add to this new condition:

```
=IF(A2=5,"green apple","red apple")
```

Basically if A1 and A2 = 5 then "green apple", otherwise "red apple".

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
=IF(AND(A1=5, B1=5), "green apple", "red apple")
```